# How to Map the clock in RTL synthesis with memory?

Tags: verilog, fpga, synthesis

I have a code for sorting a set of data in a memory. I want to synthesize this code, but I have several problems. My code has only one clock which controls every block including memory. However, I was wondering whether I need to map the clock in the entire synthesis code and memory, or only in one of them. I tried different cases and I did not get the correct answer.
This is my code:

```
module sort_top(
input Go,
input Rst,
input Clk,
input [5:0] N,
output wire [7:0] ReadData,
output reg [4:0] Address,
output reg [7:0] WriteData,
output reg MemWrite,
output reg MemRead
);
DataMemory Only_Mem(Address, WriteData, Clk, MemWrite, MemRead, ReadData); 
    parameter S_Wait = 0 , S_Initial_C = 1, S_Check_C = 2, S_Initial_D = 3, S_Read_1 = 4, S_Write_1 = 5,  S_Read_2 = 6, S_Write_2 =7, S_Swich_1 = 8, S_Swich_2 = 9, S_Update_D = 10, S_Check_D = 11, S_Update_C =12, S_Decision =13;
    reg [3:0] State;
    reg [5:0] C;
    reg signed [4:0]D;
    reg [7:0] T1,T2;
    always @(posedge Clk)begin
        if (Rst ==1) begin
            State <= S_Wait;
            C <= 5'b00000;
            D <= 5'b00000;
            T1 <= 8'h00;
            T2 <= 8'h00;
        end
        else begin
         case (State) 
            S_Wait : begin
                if (Go == 0)
                    State <= S_Wait;
                else if (Go==1)
                    State <= S_Initial_C;
            end
            S_Initial_C : begin
                C <= 6'b000001;
                State <= S_Check_C;
            end
            S_Check_C : begin
                //Address <=5'bzzzzz ;
                if (C == N)
                    State <= S_Wait;
                else if (C != 6'b100000)
                    State <= S_Initial_D;
            end
            S_Initial_D : begin
               // Address <=5'bzzzzz ;
                D <= C;
                State <= S_Read_1;
            end
            S_Read_1 : begin
                Address <= D;
                MemRead <= 1;
                MemWrite <= 0;
                State <= S_Write_1;
            end
            S_Write_1: begin
                T1 <= ReadData;
                State <= S_Read_2;    
            end
            S_Read_2 : begin
                Address <= D-1;
                MemRead <= 1;
                MemWrite <= 0;
                State <= S_Write_2;
            end
            S_Write_2 : begin
               T2 <= ReadData;
               Address <= D-1;
               MemRead <= 1;
               MemWrite <= 0;
               State <= S_Decision;  
            end 
            S_Decision: begin
                if (T2>T1)
                    State <= S_Swich_1;
                else
                    State <= S_Update_C;
           end  
            S_Swich_1 : begin
                WriteData<=T2;
                Address <=D ;
                MemWrite <= 1;
                MemRead <= 0; 
                State <= S_Swich_2;   
            end
            S_Swich_2 : begin
                WriteData <= T1 ;
                Address <=D-1 ;
                MemWrite <= 1;
                MemRead <= 0; 
                State <= S_Update_D;
            end
            S_Update_D: begin
                //Address <= 5'bzzzzz;
                MemWrite <= 0;
                MemRead <= 0;
                D <= D-1;
                State <= S_Check_D;   
            end
            S_Check_D : begin
                if (D==5'b00000)
                    State <= S_Update_C;
                else
                    State <= S_Read_1;    
            end
            S_Update_C : begin
               // Address <=5'bzzzzz ;  
                C <= C+1;
                MemWrite <= 0;
                MemRead <= 0;
                State <= S_Check_C;
            end
        endcase
        end
    end
endmodule
```

This is my XDC file which I try to synthesize this code :

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U9 [get_ports {Go}]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Go}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN E3 [get_ports Clk]                         
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports Clk]
create_clock -period 10.000 -name Clk -waveform {0.000 5.000} [get_ports Clk]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN C12 [get_ports Rst]                
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports Rst]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN R7 [get_ports {N[0]}]                  
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {N[0]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN R6 [get_ports {N[1]}]                  
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {N[1]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN R5 [get_ports {N[2]}]                  
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {N[2]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN V7 [get_ports {N[3]}]                  
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {N[3]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN V6 [get_ports {N[4]}]                  
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {N[4]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN V5 [get_ports {N[5]}]                  
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {N[5]}]

##Cellular RAM
##Bank = 14, Pin name = IO_L14N_T2_SRCC_14,                 Sch name = CRAM_CLK
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T15 [get_ports Clk]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports Clk]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN R12 [get_ports {ReadData[0]}]              
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {ReadData[0]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN T11 [get_ports {ReadData[1]}]              
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {ReadData[1]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN U12 [get_ports {ReadData[2]}]              
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {ReadData[2]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN R13 [get_ports {ReadData[3]}]              
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {ReadData[3]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN U18 [get_ports {ReadData[4]}]              
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {ReadData[4]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN R17 [get_ports {ReadData[5]}]              
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {ReadData[5]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN T18 [get_ports {ReadData[6]}]              
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {ReadData[6]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN R18 [get_ports {ReadData[7]}]              
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {ReadData[7]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN J18 [get_ports {Address[0]}]               
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Address[0]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN H17 [get_ports {Address[1]}]               
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Address[1]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN H15 [get_ports {Address[2]}]               
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Address[2]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN J17 [get_ports {Address[3]}]               
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Address[3]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN H16 [get_ports {Address[4]}]               
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {Address[4]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN F18 [get_ports {WriteData[0]}]             
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {WriteData[0]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN G18 [get_ports {WriteData[1]}]             
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {WriteData[1]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN G17 [get_ports {WriteData[2]}]             
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {WriteData[2]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN M18 [get_ports {WriteData[3]}]             
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {WriteData[3]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN M17 [get_ports {WriteData[4]}]             
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {WriteData[4]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN P18 [get_ports {WriteData[5]}]             
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {WriteData[5]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN N17 [get_ports {WriteData[6]}]             
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {WriteData[6]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN P17 [get_ports {WriteData[7]}]             
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {WriteData[7]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN R11 [get_ports MemWrite]                   
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports MemWrite]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN H14 [get_ports MemRead]                    
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports MemRead]

set_property CFGBVS VCCO [current_design]
set_property CONFIG_VOLTAGE 3.3 [current_design]
```

Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: What FPGA board are you using? Is there a 50 MHz oscillator connected to the FPGA pin E3?

Comment: Unn: I use nexys4- ddr board, when I run post synthesis simulation it does not work. I need to map Clk port both in pin E3 and ram clock? when I map Clk to both ports I face warning during implementation. I realy confused what should I do!

Comment: DataMemory is just using the internal block RAM correct? In which case, you just need to connect the Clk net to E3 as you have done (my mistake, its 100 MHz). Are you getting any warnings?

Comment: You mean that  synthesis code which is above is correct? But I face error of poor placment during Implementation.

Comment: Data memory is just using Cellular RAM.

Comment: When I just connect the Clk net to E3,I did not face any warning or error during Implementation , but I face these errors during post synthesis simulation.  
    Sim error: [XSIM 43-3225] Cannot find design unit xil_defaultlib.sort_TB in library work located at xsim.dir/work.
    Second error :  [USF-XSim 62] 'elaborate' step failed with error(s). Please check the Tcl console output or 'C:/Users/Elnaz-laptop/Desktop/Project/Insertion_Sort/Insertion_Sort.sim/sim_1/synth/func/elaborate.log' file for more information.

Comment: Sounds like xsim cannot find a testbench module (in this case called sort_TB); do you have a testbench module for your design?

Comment: Yes, I have a testbench module.This is the code of testbench:
module sort_TB(    );
reg Clk;
reg Go, Rst;

wire[4:0] Address;
wire [7:0] ReadData, WriteData;
wire MemWrite,MemRead;
integer i;

DataMemory  my_memory(Address, WriteData, Clk, MemWrite, MemRead, ReadData); 

sort_top    my_sort( Go, Rst, Clk, 6'b100000, ReadData, Address, WriteData, MemWrite, MemRead);


always begin
 Clk <=1;
 #5;
 Clk<=0;
 #5;
end

initial begin
Rst <=1;
Go<=0;

@(posedge Clk);
#5;
Rst <=0;
Go <= 1;
@(posedge Clk);
#5;
Go <=0;
end
endmodule

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are trying to route the Clk port to two different FPGA pins, which is not allowed, especially since Clk is an input.

Now I'm not sure from your description if the memory is an external device or a memory on the FPGA.

If it's on the FPGA, you shouldn't be declaring FPGA pins for it's ports.

If it's external, then the memory model should be instantiated in the testbench and not inside the top level of your chip design. In this case, you probably need to forward your clock input to a separate clock output to drive the memory IC clock, assuming this is the way you have it hooked up on your PCB.

Comment: The memory is  on the Fpga and I do not have any external device. You mean that I did not need to declar the CLk pin for the RAM sepreatly and I only need to declar the CLk as input? But when I do this in post synthesis simulation I face whit error.

Comment: Your XDC file should only declare the pins associated with the top level of your FPGA, not internal modules. Therefore, you only declare your clk input once, for the top level.

Comment: Also, since the RAM is internal to your design, you don't need to define all the RAM ports as inputs and outputs from sort_top unless you need to make them available externally to your FPGA.

Comment: Thank you very much.I need RAM ports as outputs externally on my FPGA but I only have 16 LEDs, how can I map 23 outputs? should I use 7 segment? how can I map 8 bits output to 7 segment?

Comment: You probably only really need your RAM ReadData as outputs which could be mapped to 7 of your LEDs. Then you could incrementally step through your address range to show that your has been sorted.